# Regex: either only numbers or alphanumeric with '-' and '_'allowed but not number with '-' and '-'

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I getting trouble pattern matching, I am trying to generate pattern which can accept either only numbers or alphanumeric with '`-`' and '`_`' allowed but not not number with '`-`' and '`-`' allowed and only '`-`' and '`_`' should not be allowed.

I tried the below one which somewhat working fine but fully working.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$
```

I am trying to match cases like:

```
abcd = OK
as123 = Ok
as_as = Ok
as_12 = Ok
as-as = ok
12as = Ok
12_1as = Ok
123_12 = not Ok
12-12 = not Ok
1234 = ok
-- = not ok
__ = not ok
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you allow only one - or _ or can there be several? If several, should they all be the same or can one mix? Can they be at the beginning or end?

Comment: no only single also cannot be entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```js
var test = [
    'abcd',
    'as123',
    'as_as',
    'as_12',
    'as-as',
    '12as',
    '12_1as',
    '123_12',
    '12-12',
    '1234',
    '--',
    '__',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' : '+/^(?!\d+[-_]\d+$)[a-z0-9]+[-_]?[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(a);
}));
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of string
  (?!       : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
    [-_]    : - or _
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
    $       : end of string
  )         : end lookahead
  [a-z0-]+  : 1 or more alphanumeric character
  [-_]?     : optional - or _
  [a-z0-]+  : 1 or more alphanumeric character
$           : end of string
```

Comment: Clear I think *...which can accept either only numbers*

Comment: Also it does not match `ab-cd_ef`

Comment: @revo: Thanks for downvote. This is not in OP's test cases.

Comment: Thank you correspondingly.  Not OP's test case but OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for such regex which benefits from a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!\d*(?:[-_]+\d*)*$)[\w-]+$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5QXCf/3)

Comment: is possible to eliminate those which only excepting '__' or '----' else  its working fine.